# Program that changes military time to standard time

Tags: java, time, format

```
    public class Time
    {
      private int time = 1200;
      private int hour = 00;
      private int minute = 00;

       public Time ()
      {
        time = 1200;

      }

      public Time (int h, int m)
      {
        hour = h;
        minute= m;

      }

      public String toString()
      {
        hour =time % 1000; 

        return hour;
      }
  }
```

I was wondering how I could use modulus                                                                   to set the two digits as the hour variable.

Comment: If you need standard time, which I assume means 8 AM vs 8 PM, don't you think you'd need an AM/PM indicator too? --- Also, what's the point of having both `time` and `hour`/`minute`? Which are you using?

Comment: consider `System.out.println(1200 / 100);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use some of Java's inbuilt functionality like `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` you can do something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("James Mathis's 24-hour (Miltary) to 12-hour time converter");
    System.out.println("==========================================================");
    System.out.print("Please enter a 24 time in the format hh:mm (example: 13:45):");

    Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input24Time = scanIn.nextLine();
    scanIn.close();
    System.out.println("24-hour (Military) Time entered: " + input24Time);

    try {
      final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm");
      final Date dateObj = sdf.parse(input24Time);
      String timein12Format = new SimpleDateFormat("K:mm a").format(dateObj);
      System.out.println("The equivalent 12 hour time is: " + timein12Format);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/Ec7U/0)